# My WD 1TB hard disk has jumbled up data

Tags: hard-drive

My WD 1TB hard disk has jumbled up data, while playing one video file, I can see scenes of another video file at many points. This file I copied in a pen drive and same problem occurred. When this is happening the vlc is also in hang mode

Comment: I've had this more than once with drives that had been connected to a Windows system. There is, or was at that point, a bug in the driver. There is not a lot you can do, except perhaps moving all video files away from the drive, reformatting the drive, and putting the files back again.